# get magento 2 rest api data on specific page or record between such as 100-150

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am finding solution get magento2 product data via rest api page by page  .
I am currently using below search Criteria

```
mydomaim.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=12
```

but I need get results page by page because if i have 5000 product i have to set page size 5000 .

I checked doc there is `searchCriteria[currentPage]` but nothing found for  nth page results.

is there any searchCriteria to accomplish this.

I need Get Results using multiple requests

as example
first request return  1-200 products
second request return 201-400 results
I need some searchCriteria to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html

You can put your condition & use

> searchCriteria[pageSize] - Specifies the maximum number of items to
>   return. The value must be an integer. If the pageSize is not
>   specified, the system returns all matches.

https://cyrillschumacher.com/2015/01/02/magento2---search-parameters-for-the-rest-api/

```
"current_page": 1, 
"page_size": 10
```

You have to Use Both in your case

Comment: yes.but if i want get result  between  200-400  how i achieve it. I need to minimize results for single request and get page by page results multiple request

Comment: @srinathmadusanka Please check updated answer

Comment: Most welcome @srinathmadusanka